# Фильтрация html в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

требуется на всех картинках jpg именно jpg заменить с http на https
есть

> add_filter('the_content','my_code_filter2', 1);

он фильтрует то что находится в the_content.
Но в предоставленном мне шаблоне помимо вывода the_content, есть ещё вывод от плагинов и вывод из базы вручную в html на одной странице. Соответственно фильтруется только то что выходит из the_content, а остальное нет.

Подскажите есть ли способ в wordpress сначало собрать весь вывод html в переменную, отфильтровать ее и уже тогда вывести)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того, как устроена ваша тема, из каких файлов .php идет вывод. Но общая идея такая. Оберните нужный участок кода в буферизацию php:

```
ob_start();
// Здесь ваш код...
$output = ob_get_clean();
// Здесь замена подстрок в $output ...
echo $output;
```

Можно попробовать скопировать index.php в дочернюю тему и править его подобным образом.

Comment: то что нужно, Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

> требуется на всех картинках jpg именно jpg заменить с http на https

Это можно сделать с плагином https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Но вообще это не обязательно (если ничего не поломано). ВП по дефолту подставляет `srcset` на запрошенном протоколе.